# Antlr4: testing C#-parser

Tags: c#, antlr4

Is there something like `grun` (`org.artlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig`) for antlr4cs? (https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs)

I would like to avoid generating the java code, just to be able to test the grammar.

Comment: Use the NuGet package, the code is automatically generated at compile-time, and you'll get to test the real thing.

Comment: I already installed the NuGet package acording to the ‘Getting Started’ at the github page and also get the generated code. But how can I use this for testing in terms of seing a parse tree?

Answer (score 0):

Opened the grammar and the test-input file in antlrworks2 — did the trick and showed a parse-tree (select tab with grammar, “Run” -> “Run in TestRig…” -> choose input file and start rule).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately TestRig doesn't work in antlr4cs. You can try to use Java version for TestRig only (I didn't tried that).

Other solution (poor-man) is to write unit tests that will print string representation of parse tree. It's not the best solution but I was able to work with it quite efficiently without fighting differences between Java and C# version